# Always go to the Welcome Page in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, login

Is it possible to always direct users to the Welcome Page in SharePoint, when using login as an other user or when requesting a sub site, page in the browser?

Comment: By default, all users already go to the Welcome page.  Is there a problem you are trying to solve or something unique to your environment (i.e. is this a kiosk?)

Comment: I trying to make it so that if you are in a sub site or another page. And then select login as another user, the new user is sent to the Welcome page, not the sub site or page the previous users was on.

Answer (score 1):

One route you could go is using the AdditionalPageHead delegate control.  This allows you to add custom User Controls that load everywhere the SharePoint master page loads.  (I have an example on how to use the delegate control on my blog: http://www.sharepointjohn.com/sharepoint-2010-programmatically-add-javascript-meta-tags-and-css-styles-to-the-header-of-every-page/).

In that user control, you could set a cookie or session variable that says "I've already redirected this person" so that each time your code runs, it first checks to see if this has been set and if not, redirect the user after setting it.

Answer (score 0):

I can advise you to craete custom content page with custom code behind logic and after deploy set this page a Welcome page.

This way you will have a full control about what you are doing and how users are redirected.

Hope it helps,

Andrew

Comment: Would like to know if there is a setting in SharePoint for this first.

Comment: As I know, there is no OOTB option to do this.